# Passing Donation Amount to PayPal Page

Tags: paypal

In the past I was able to add a form so a user could add a donation amount on the website and it would send that amount to the PayPal checkout page. It seems that PayPal has changed how this works and I am having issues figuring out how to pass that amount. I am hoping someone here has gotten this to work. Here is my current code and dev site for testing purposes.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="VMUWQGHWEATL8" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<!-- Text Input Boxes -->
<div class="donate-wrapper">
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount">
<p style="color: #fff">Monthly donation options on the next screen.</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="continue" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</div>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

Dev site: https://braindonordev.wpengine.com/support-us/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it.  Create a new button via http://www.paypal.com/buttons , and in Step 2 uncheck the option to save the button at PayPal.  Then when you have generated your button code, click the option to remove the code protection.

Now you have "unhosted" HTML you can edit.

The unfortunate thing when passing a donation amount is there won't be an option to make the donation recurring, so you would need a separate relabeled "Subscribe" button for that.  Relabled meaning, replace the image with one that says "Donate".

---

Alternatively, just keep the basic Donate button that you have to serve both use cases (recurring and non-recurring). It's intuitive enough, and has a nice big amount box on the next screen and checkbox to make it recurring:

[image]

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@redcross.org">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="text" name="amount">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This gives me some options to work with the client on.

Comment: If you really want to be fancy, you can have the recurring option on your site and dynamically change whether you submit a "_donations" or "subscription" redirection to PayPal.  The redirection doesn't have to be an HTML form, when you generate your button at PayPal if there are not dropdown options  in the form, there will be an "E-mail" tab that gives a standard URL you can adapt to your needs

Comment: I think Paypal has updated the button making process since you did it last because the steps don't include some of what you are describing. Can you please take a look at the button making process and update your answer or do you have some example code that might work with a few changes on my end? Thanks.

Comment: The new factory huh. Well start with a 'Buy Now' button and follow my instructions for that. In the resulting code, change the cmd parameter to "_donations". It will work just the same.  You'll want to change the image to the one that says donate.

Comment: I tried to do this and it still didn't work. Do you having any working code for this situation that I could take a look at. Thanks.

Comment: "It still didn't work" does not provide a description of the problem. But okay, it's trivial to create the HTML for such a button.

Comment: Thanks for your patients on this with me @Preston. I have things working now.